# cannot start remote desktop on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I spent a couple of hours on this already but was unable to fix the problem. When starting up the Windows Remote Desktop application I get the following error:

"The system cannot find the file specified. C:\WINDOWS\system32\<-LANG_NAME->\mstsc.exe.MUI"

However, the file referred to does exist, and is in the system32\en-US\ folder. A few of the forums I was searching through suggested installing a Windows update (KB969084) which I did but it made no difference.

I recently updated from SP2 to SP3, and also from IE7 to IE8, and I read that either of these updates can cause certain registry entries to become corrupted so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: When you say 'start the windows remote desktop application' do you mean the remote desktop service that allows other people to connect to your machine or the Remote Desktop Client on your machine?

Comment: Hi, it's under Accessories: "Remote Desktop Connection".

Comment: @Richie086, that's the desktop client.  Did you restart, as per this [post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/remote-desktop-error-the-system-cannot-find-the/ba7b6a96-447b-4072-bb28-14927d990191)?

Comment: yes, I did restart my PC.

Comment: Try This:
However what did work was to delete (or rename adding .BAK extension) mstsc.exe and mstscax.dll in SafeMode (Windows would immediately rebuild the files if deleted in regular mode) and to install the KB969084. Then restart. Everything works now.

Same post at bottom

Comment: the files have an .mui extension, ie: mstsc.exe.mui and mstscax.dll.mui should I try deleting them anyway?

Comment: Well, I just tried that and it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I used the Remote Desktop Client from `\sp3gdr` folder
and got the same error.

Then i copied *.MUI files to new subfolders

named

```
\ru-ru
```

and

```
\en-us
```

respectively 
for

```
WindowsXP-kb969084-x86-RUS_659a7bcea0a75bbd458a646a5321ce7725594123.zip
```

and

```
WindowsXP-kb969084-x86-ENU_153587172bf060ddc9d2c966f1eaaf4f47926f28.zip
```

versions, that were simply renamed from .exe (SFX .CAB) updates

downloaded from [catalog.update.microsoft.com/ kb969084 search result page](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb969084).

And it works for me. RDP clients seems to be portable
and error message suppressed.

Use as workaround!

P.S. My operating system is **Windows 7** `(6.1 build 7601) Ultimate` (Russian: Максимальная), Service Pack 1